# How can I get the percentage of utilization for each cpu?

Tags: bash, shell, cpu-usage

I wrote a script to get the percentage of utilization for each cpu based on a script that I have found that gave the average percentage of utilization. The script that I have found works great, the percentage changes every second. Unfortunately the percentages displayed by the script I wrote don't change at all. Do you have an idea of what I did wrong or if you have a better idea to get the percentage of utilization for each cpu ?

**EDIT**

The working part is the "GET THE MEAN USAGE OF THE CPU" part, the non working part is the "GET THE MAX USAGE BETWEEN ALL THE CPUS"

Here is my script, it displays the avg cpu usage and the cpu that is used the most :

```
#!/bin/bash


PREV_TOTAL=0
PREV_IDLE=0

while true; do

# GET THE MEAN USAGE OF THE CPU
# -----------------------------
  # we get the mean of the cpu usage
  CPU=(`cat /proc/stat | grep '^cpu '`) # Get the total CPU statistics.
  unset CPU[0]                          # Discard the "cpu" prefix.
  IDLE=${CPU[4]}
  # Calculate the total CPU time.
  TOTAL=0
  for VALUE in "${CPU[@]:0:4}"; do
    let "TOTAL=$TOTAL+$VALUE"
  done

  # Calculate the CPU usage since we last checked.
  let "DIFF_IDLE=$IDLE-$PREV_IDLE"
  let "DIFF_TOTAL=$TOTAL-$PREV_TOTAL"
  let "DIFF_USAGE=(1000*($DIFF_TOTAL-$DIFF_IDLE)/$DIFF_TOTAL+5)/10"

  # Remember the total and idle CPU times for the next check.
  PREV_TOTAL="$TOTAL"
  PREV_IDLE="$IDLE"

# GET THE MAX USAGE BETWEEN ALL THE CPUS
# --------------------------------------

  # here we get an array with all the cpus
  CPUS=(`cat /proc/stat | grep '^cpu[0-9]'`)
  lengthArray=${#CPUS[@]}
  numberOfCpus=$((lengthArray/11))
  i=0
  numberOfCpus=$((lengthArray/11))
  TOTALS=()
  IDLES=()
  PERCENTAGES=()
  PREV_TOTALS=()
  PREV_IDLES=()
  # we instenciate the arrays and set their values to 0
  while [ $i -lt $numberOfCpus ]; do
    TOTALS+=(0)
    IDLES+=(0)
    PERCENTAGES+=(0)
    PREV_TOTALS+=(0)
    PREV_IDLES+=(0)
    i=$((i+1))
  done

  i=0
  index=1
  limit=$((index+4))
  # we loop through the array to get each total for each cpu
  while [ $i -lt $numberOfCpus ]; do
    IDLES[$i]=${CPUS[$index+3]}
    # since we only want the first four numbers for each cpu, we have to loop in a strange way
    while [ $index -lt $limit ]; do
        TOTALS[$i]=$((TOTALS[$i]+CPUS[$index]))
        index=$((index+1))
    done
    # 7 is the number of array element before the next series of number that we want 
    index=$((limit+7))
    # we set the limit to four+the index because we only want the four numbers after the index
    limit=$((index+4))
    i=$((i+1))
  done

  # now we calculate the percentage of usage for every cpu so we can get the max percentage
  i=0

  # we calculate the percentage for each cpu
  while [ $i -lt $numberOfCpus ]; do
    let "DIFF_IDLE_i=${IDLES[$i]}-${PREV_IDLES[$i]}"
    let "DIFF_TOTAL_i=${TOTALS[$i]}-${PREV_TOTALS[$i]}"
    let "DIFF_USAGE_i=(1000*($DIFF_TOTAL_i-$DIFF_IDLE_i)/$DIFF_TOTAL_i+5)/10"
    PERCENTAGES[$i]=$DIFF_USAGE_i
    PREV_TOTALS[$i]=${TOTALS[$i]}
    PREV_IDLES[$i]=${IDLES[$i]}
    i=$((i+1))
  done

  MAX=${PERCENTAGES[0]}
  cpu=0
  i=0
  # here we look for the max
  for percent in ${PERCENTAGES[@]}; do
    if [ $percent -gt $MAX ]; then
        cpu=$i
        MAX=$percent
    fi
    i=$((i+1))
  done

  echo -en "\rCPU: $DIFF_USAGE%   CPU$cpu: $MAX%  \b\b"

  # Wait before checking again.
  sleep 1
done
```

Answer (score 0):

I have finally found my problem, I initialized my arrays in the loop, and it needed to be initialized outside the loop. I managed to make the script work, if anyone is interested, here is the final script:

```
#!/bin/bash

# this function is used to get the infos about the cpu
getCpuScores() {
    CPU=(`cat /proc/stat | grep ^cpu$1`)
}

# this function is used to get the percentage of utilization of a cpu
getPercentageOfCpu() {
    unset CPU[0]
    local idle=${CPU[4]}
    local total=0
    for val in "${CPU[@]:0:4}"; do
        let "total=$total+$val"
    done

    let "diff_idle=$idle-${PREV_IDLES[$1]}"
    let "diff_total=$total-${PREV_TOTALS[$1]}"
    let "diff_usage=(1000*($diff_total-$diff_idle)/$diff_total+5)/10"

    PERCENTAGES[$1]=$diff_usage
    PREV_IDLES[$1]=$idle
    PREV_TOTALS[$1]=$total
}


# first we initialize all the needed variables
PREV_TOTAL=0
PREV_IDLE=0
# this is to get the number of cpu
CPUS=(`cat /proc/stat | grep '^cpu[0-9]'`)
lengthArray=${#CPUS[@]}
numberOfCpus=$((lengthArray/11))
i=0
PREV_TOTALS=()
PREV_IDLES=()
PERCENTAGES=()
# we instenciate the arrays and set their values to 0
while [ $i -lt $numberOfCpus ]; do
    PREV_TOTALS+=(0)
    PREV_IDLES+=(0)
    PERCENTAGES+=(0)
    i=$((i+1))
done

# MAIN LOOP

while true; do

# GET THE MEAN USAGE OF THE CPU
# -----------------------------
  # we get the mean of the cpu usage
  CPU=(`cat /proc/stat | grep '^cpu '`) # Get the total CPU statistics.
  unset CPU[0]                          # Discard the "cpu" prefix.
  IDLE=${CPU[4]}
  # Calculate the total CPU time.
  TOTAL=0
  for VALUE in "${CPU[@]:0:4}"; do
    let "TOTAL=$TOTAL+$VALUE"
  done

  # Calculate the CPU usage since we last checked.
  let "DIFF_IDLE=$IDLE-$PREV_IDLE"
  let "DIFF_TOTAL=$TOTAL-$PREV_TOTAL"
  let "DIFF_USAGE=(1000*($DIFF_TOTAL-$DIFF_IDLE)/$DIFF_TOTAL+5)/10"

  # Remember the total and idle CPU times for the next check.
  PREV_TOTAL="$TOTAL"
  PREV_IDLE="$IDLE"

# GET THE MAX USAGE BETWEEN ALL THE CPUS
# ------------------------
  # first we get the percentage of utilization for each cpu
  i=0
  while [ $i -lt $numberOfCpus ]; do
    # we get the cpu score to be able to calculate the percentage of utilization
    getCpuScores $i
    # then we calculate the percentage of the cpu and put it in an array
    getPercentageOfCpu $i

    i=$((i+1))

  done

  # then we get the max
  MAX=${PERCENTAGES[0]}
  cpu=0
  i=0

  while [ $i -lt $numberOfCpus ]; do
    if [ ${PERCENTAGES[$i]} -gt $MAX ]; then
        MAX=${PERCENTAGES[$i]}
        cpu=$i
    fi
    i=$((i+1))
  done

  # finally we display the avg cpu usage and the max cpu usage
  echo -en "\rCPU: $DIFF_USAGE%  CPU$cpu: $MAX% \b\b"

  # Wait before checking again.
  sleep 1
done
```

The script displays the percentage of the average cpu usage and the percentage of usage of the cpu that is used the most.